Sequoia 2000 benchmark dataset
I'm recreating the DBSCAN cluster algorithm which uses the Sequoia 2000 benchmark dataset. There's an old question here that has a link for the dataset, but I've been doing more research and I can't find anything more about what this dataset actually is and why it's so hard to find. The link provided I can't get anywhere else too so I'm not sure if I should g ahead and download. Does anyone know more about the public sourcing of the dataset?

Is this what you're looking for?
Background information can be found in e.g. Stonebraker et al. (1993).
